# Multi-path TCP in Ubuntu

Tags: cisco

Q1.How can install Multipath TCP in Ubuntu?

Q2.Can I do install in Cisco Packet Tracer or another software?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su], [unix.se], or [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R1: follow the instruction given by the authors on [this page](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/AptRepository), which are:

> For the newest release, please follow the below steps:
>
> First, add the gpg-apt-key with:
>
> `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61`
>
> Then, just add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list:
>
> `deb https://dl.bintray.com/cpaasch/deb jessie main`
>
> Now, install MPTCP with the following:
>
> `sudo apt-get update   sudo apt-get install linux-mptcp`
>
> And reboot your machine.
>
> Now, it's time you configure routing as described [here](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/ConfigureRouting).

R2: Packet Tracer is a Cisco product, it is proprietary and you cannot modify it.
For other software, if they are open-source and you have the knowldge and time to dig in, why not?

Comment: Thanks, I have done configuration routing. after then how can I complete the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: The instructions are on the official site of multipath TCP: https://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/AptRepository

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here. Please consider adding more details to your answer so it remains useful even after the linked document changes or is removed.